# How could I make .gitignore exclude works to ignore everthing in /AppData but still index my /AppData/Roaming/doublecmd/doublecmd.xml?

Tags: git, gitignore

Problem context: I'm using Windows but plan to version control my home folder  with git, in Windows's user folder there is `AppData` folder and my Double Commander application's setting is in it, so I need to :

1. ignore everythig in `%USERPROFILE%` folder except some setting
2. ignore everything in `USERPROFILE%\AppData` folder except `/AppData/Roaming/doublecmd/doublecmd.xml`

After reading [git manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) , I've tried to save my `.gitignore` as:

```
/*
!.minttyrc
!/AppData
/AppData/*
!/AppData/Roaming/doublecmd/doublecmd.xml
```

tried with more detailed, failed also.

```
/*
!.minttyrc
!/AppData
/AppData/*
!/AppData/Roaming
/Appdata/Roaming/*
!/AppData/Roaming/doublecmd/doublecmd.xml
```

How could I make `.gitignore` exclude works to ignore everthing in `/AppData` but still index my `/AppData/Roaming/doublecmd/doublecmd.xml`?

[git manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> Example to exclude everything except a specific directory `foo/bar` (note the `/*` - without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude everything within `foo/bar`):

```
$ cat .gitignore
# exclude everything except directory foo/bar
/*
!/foo
/foo/*
!/foo/bar
```

Comment: The example from the manual that you cite shows you exactly what to do. But you are not doing it!

Comment: as you can see in this image https://imgur.com/kbPp2St I did tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: Not at all. What I’m saying is, you provided from the docs a model of how to do this (“Example to exclude everything except a specific directory“) but you are not doing what that model shows.

Answer (score 1):

This `.gitignore` will ignore everything in `AppData` but the file you specified

```sh
# Ignore everything in AppData
/AppData/*
# Do not ignore AppData/Roaming/doublecmd/doublecmd.xml
!/AppData/Roaming/doublecmd/doublecmd.xml
```

You don't need to write `!.gitignore` in the `.gitignore` file because it is not possible to ignore that file, also you don't need to write `!.minttyrc` because that will not be excluded since you have not specified to ignore everything in the root directory with a `/*`

Comment: Note: just because it doesn't seem necessary for us to use `/*` doesn't mean that OP doesn't need it. He might have a use-case unbeknownst to us for ignoring everything in his repo. Your answer might break the rest of his project (potentially)

Comment: @mnestorov I can only answer what the user asked, which is _ignore everthing in `/AppData` but still index my `/AppData/Roaming/doublecmd/doublecmd.xml`_ and my answer does just that without breaking the rest of the project. Also you cannot un-ignore `.gitignore` which is what `!.gitignore` would do but doesn't. And again, user used `/*` just because he saw that from the git manual, and not because he wanted it to be there, hence my other suggestion.

Comment: You have answer that **part** of the question, but he also has put `/*` there for a reason. You shouldn't assume he doesn't need that general ignore statement.

Comment: @mnestorov as I said, it looks like he copied that from the git manual trying to achieve what he was asking for.

Comment: thanks @MattiaRighetti, I've update post to include my problem context

Comment: i've tried your solution but it still doesn't work

Comment: It looks like you are editing the incorrect `.gitignore`, on the left panel you are in `C:\Users\longnx` while you are using `git status` in a folder named `MINGW64`. I have replicated the folder and the files that you are trying to hide and it works on my machine, you must be doing something incorrectly or you have a different folder tree structure different from the one you have described.

Comment: @MattiaRighetti I'm using git on Windows, the MINGW64 is a shell, the yellow `~` is equivalent to `C:\Users\longnx`